# AND in Lua, how is it processed?

Tags: lua, logic, operators, stdout

I saw this code in a [Lua Style Guide](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide)

```
print(x == "yes" and "YES!" or x)
```

Context:

```
local function test(x)
  print(x == "yes" and "YES!" or x)
  -- rather than if x == "yes" then print("YES!") else print(x) end
end
```

What exactly happens at " x == "yes" and "YES!" ?
Why does it print "YES!" or (x) not "true" or (x) ?

EDIT:

Is it like:

```
X == "yes"               -- > true
true and (value)         -- > value
print( (x == "yes") and value)
```

So checking x for the value "yes" results in true, adding true to a value gives the value and printing this process prints the value, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html):

> The operator and returns its first argument if it is false; otherwise, it returns its second argument.

Therefore, `true and "YES!"` evaluates to `"YES!"`.

This scheme works because if the first argument is falsy, the whole expression will become falsy (the same as the first argument); otherwise it will become the same as the second argument, which iff that is truthy will make the whole expression truthy.

Comment: So on binary level, adding "true" means adding '1' to every field, which results in the same value as before?

Comment: @Sempie: I'm not sure what you mean.  Maybe you can express it in code (or just try it out).

Comment: @Sempie "binary level"... You are over-thinking this. `nil` and `false` are falsey, all other values are truthy. Think [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) not binary bits. `and` and `or` are selection operators, as documented.